how do you update a separate combobox text property with a listview SelectedItem property?
I have a full property called SelectedLocation in a view model that is bound to the combobox text property. I am trying to update this property with the selecteditem of a listview DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SelectedLocation}" . Every other control updates as the expected.
I have tried setting the combobox IsEditable property to true. Just so we are clear, there is a propertychanged call on this SelectedLocation property. I have also tried binding the combobox selectedItem property to this same property.
     public string SelectedLocation
 {
        get
        {
             return _selectedLocation;
        }
        set
        {
             IsEditable = true;
             ReadOnlyTrue = false;
             if (value != null && _selectedLocation != value)
             {
                    _selectedLocation = value;

                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedLocation));

                    ValidateProperty(nameof(SelectedLocation));

             }

        }
 }

The text portion of the combobox does not update no matter which binding I try. I have been all over the internet including this site but have had no success.
<ComboBox x:Name="cboLocations" 
        IsEditable="{Binding IsEditable}"
        IsReadOnly="{Binding ReadOnlyTrue}"
        Grid.Column="1" 
        Grid.Row="1"
        Margin="10,0,10,0" 
        Text="{Binding SelectedPhone.SelectedLocation}"
        DisplayMemberPath="{Binding ElementName=lvPhone, Path=}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding PhoneLocations}"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" >

Here is the ListView I am trying to get the info from:
<ListView x:Name="lvPhone"
         Grid.Row="1"
         ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentEmployeePhones}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPhone,Mode=OneWayToSource}"
         
         Margin="0,24,0,56" SelectionChanged="lvPhone_SelectionChanged">
        <ListView.View>
                 <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Phone Number"
                                     Width="500"
                                     DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PhoneNumber}" />

                            <GridViewColumn Header="Location"
                                     Width="120"
                                     DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SelectedLocation}" />

                            <GridViewColumn Header="Is Primary"
                                     Width="120"
                                     DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding IsPrimaryPhone,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                 </GridView>
        </ListView.View>


Is there any code you can share?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
